# Dynamically check if an object supports dynamic member lookup

Tags: swift

Is there a way in Swift 4.2 to tell if an arbitrary object supports dynamic member lookup?

Something like the example below.

```
func getName(of object: AnyObject) -> String? {
    if let object = object as? DynamicMemberLookupProtocol {
        return object["name"]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible at the moment.

However, after [SR-8077
Compile error when using @dynamicMemberLookup as a protocol requirement](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8077) bug gets fixed in a production version of swift (hopefully, in swift 5), we can have a workaround for that in the form of protocols, constrained by `@dynamicMemberLookup`.

You can also read [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0195-dynamic-member-lookup.md) on why `@dynamicMemberLookup` was not implemented as a protocol:

> We started with the approach of making this be a protocol that types conform to to get this behavior. It turns out that this behavior is very non-protocol like: it is not useful to define generic algorithms over, and existential values are only useful if they define a specific subscript that implements the requirements implicit in this attribute.
>
> For these and other reasons, defining this as a protocol doesn't really fit into the design of Swift.